# Laravel file upload

Tags: php, file, upload, laravel

Getting the following error

Unable to create the "http://website.com/public/uploads/" directory

My code:

```
$file = Input::file('upload');
$file_name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
$file_size = round($file->getSize() / 1024);
$file_ex = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
$file_mime = $file->getMimeType();

if (!in_array($file_ex, array('jpg', 'gif', 'png'))) return Redirect::to('/')->withErrors('Invalid image extension we just allow JPG, GIF, PNG');

 $newname = $file_name;
 $file->move(URL::to('/').'/uploads/', $newname);
```

The uploads folder exists.

Comment: Sounds like the directory is not writable. Try chmod 777 or 755 with your webserver user as the dir owner. Also: you should use absolute file paths not URL's when trying to move a file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to move a file to a URL, you have to move to a folder:

```
$file->move(base_path().'/public/uploads/', $newname);
```

Answer (score 2):

It can also be done like this:

```
$file->move('uploads', $newname);
```

For a unique file name, you can add `time()` function  like this:

```
$file_name = time().$file->getClientOriginalName();
$file->move('uploads', $newname);
```