# Laravel saving image to public folder?

Tags: image, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

So I am trying to save uploaded image to laravel/public folder and return src so a path to where the file has been saved, however nothing happens after I choose an image and I get no errors, what might be wrong?

```
public function testing(Request $request) {
    if(Input::file())
    {
        $image = Input::file('img');
        $filename = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $path = public_path('images/' . $filename);
        Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize(200, 200)->save($path);
        $user->image = $filename;
        $user->save();
    }
}


<form action="{{ action('BuilderController@testing') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form" method="POST">
    <input id="img" class="form-control filestyle margin images" data-input="false" type="file" data-buttonText="Upload Logo" data-size="sm" data-badge="false" onchange="uploadImage();" />
</form>
```

Comment: Please can you show the contents of `uploadImage()` also can show the the output for `dd($request->allFiles())`?]

Comment: nothing relevant there, I just tried to do it using different method function uploadImage()
{
 var img = document.getElementById("img").src;
 alert(img);
} and dd gives me nothing

Comment: You don't appear to be submitting the form?!

Comment: That is probobly the problem however I don't want to have a submit button, how can I do that using ajax?

Comment: http://www.dropzonejs.com/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5 Uploading and display image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42594190/laravel-5-uploading-and-display-image)

Answer (score 8):

Try with `move()` method?

```
$filename = time().'.'.request()->img->getClientOriginalExtension();
request()->img->move(public_path('images'), $filename);

$user->image=$filename;
$user->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `name="img"`on your form.

Answer (score -1):

You can easily upload image to public folder as following:

```
 $image = $request->file('image');

$input['imagename'] = time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();

$destinationPath = public_path('/thumbnail');

$img = Image::make($image->getRealPath());

$img->resize(100, 100, function ($constraint) {

    $constraint->aspectRatio();

})->save($destinationPath.'/'.$input['imagename']);

/*After Resize Add this Code to Upload Image*/
$destinationPath = public_path('/');


$image->move($destinationPath, $input['imagename']);
```

And also you can check it here to resize and upload image:

http://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-5-image-upload-and-resize-example-using-intervention-image-packageexample.html

Answer (score -1):

Make sure in the form you include enctype. Otherwise your file will not be submitted

```
<form action="#" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

</form>
```

Answer (score -2):

First, you have not added file input name

```
if(Input::file('inputname')){
//
}
```

Secondly,

For laravel-5.3 You can determine if a file is present on the request using the hasFile method

```
if ($request->hasFile('photo')) {
    //
}
```

And you can retrieve the uploaded file

```
$file = $request->file('photo');
```

You can find the complete documentation here

> https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests#files

Comment: I get: Creating default object from empty value however image is being saved why?